# Recursively scan directories in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a bash script that scans directories in current directory and generate md5 checksum values for each file in directory tree. It also should keep relative path to file and print checksums in a file.

For example if directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── d
│   ├── file1.c
│   └── file2.c
├── e
│   └── file3.c
└── f
    └── file4.cpp
```

The output should be something like this:

```
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  d/file1.c
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  d/file2.c
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  e/file3.c
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  f/file4.cpp
```

But I can't find a way to keep path to file when cd to them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
```

or...

```
find . -type f | xargs -n 1 -d "\n" md5sum
```

Comment: You can vastly improve performance by using the `+` terminator with `find` in lieu of `\;`;  The former collects multiple arguments to pass as a block to the `-exec`.  The later spawns a process for **every** argument.  Process instantiation is costly.  In some systems, the `-exec ... ()+` may outperform a pipeline to `xargs`.